# How to make Vba select from drop down list without calling each index of that list?

Tags: vba, dropdown

I have a drop down with a list, and whenever its selected it shows the data on my vba dashboard. However, I don't what to do an infinite amount of IFs statements. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()

    Dim X As Worksheet
    Set X = Sheets("Sheet1")


   If ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).OLEFormat.Object.ListIndex = 1 Then
        lastRow = TC.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If TC.Cells(i, 1) = "England" Then
                A = WorksheetFunction.Concat(A, Chr(10), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4))
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Circle 1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = A
            End If
            If TC.Cells(i, 3) = "Yes" And TC.Cells(i, 1) = "England" Then
                B = WorksheetFunction.Concat(B, Chr(10), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4))
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Circle 2").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = B
            ElseIf TC.Cells(i, 3) = "No" And TC.Cells(i, 1) = "England" Then
                C = WorksheetFunction.Concat(C, Chr(10), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4))
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Circle 3").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = C

            End If
        Next i
   If ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).OLEFormat.Object.ListIndex = 2 Then
        lastRow = TC.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If TC.Cells(i, 1) = "Scotland" Then
                A = WorksheetFunction.Concat(A, Chr(10), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4))
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Circle 1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = A
            End If
            If TC.Cells(i, 3) = "Yes" And TC.Cells(i, 1) = "Scotland" Then
                B = WorksheetFunction.Concat(B, Chr(10), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4))
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Circle 2").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = B
            ElseIf TC.Cells(i, 3) = "No" And TC.Cells(i, 1) = "Scotland" Then
                C = WorksheetFunction.Concat(C, Chr(10), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4))
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Circle 3").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = C

            End If
        Next i
   If ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).OLEFormat.Object.ListIndex =3 Then
        lastRow = TC.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If TC.Cells(i, 1) = "Germany" Then
                A = WorksheetFunction.Concat(A, Chr(10), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4))
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Circle 1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = A
            End If
            If TC.Cells(i, 3) = "Yes" And TC.Cells(i, 1) = "Germany" Then
                B = WorksheetFunction.Concat(B, Chr(10), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4))
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Circle 2").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = B
            ElseIf TC.Cells(i, 3) = "No" And TC.Cells(i, 1) = "Germany" Then
                C = WorksheetFunction.Concat(C, Chr(10), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4))
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Circle 3").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = C

            End If
        Next i
```

And so on and so forth for all different countries.

Comment: Would help to show the code for at least two countries, or it's difficult/impossible to pick out the patterns in the code. What if the ListIndex is not 1? Also a bunch of variables with no declarations - are they Globals or ?

Comment: If this code is in the worksheet code module, then you can /should refer to the sheet using `Me` - eg.   `Me.Shapes`

Comment: @TimWilliams I added more countries, its a repeated of the same if else statement, the index changes when the dropdown list selects that particular country. Just hoping I could call whatever is selected to do that code.